# Find the value of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(e-\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}\right).$

Tags: calculus

We know $$e=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{k!}.$$ But in the question the upper bound of the second sum is $n$ so we can't write $e$ directly. Since upper bound of $n$ is $\infty$ so tried to split the summations to get a clue. The given sum is:

$\left(e-\frac 1{0! }\right) +\left[e-\left(\frac 1{0!}+\frac{1}{1! }\right) \right]+\cdots+\left[e-\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{0! }+\frac{1}{1! }+\frac 1{2! }+\cdots\infty\right)}_{=e}\right].$

Now I'm clueless. The last few terms tend to $0$ but how to handle the other terms? Please suggest something. I haven't dealt with infinite sums that much, I have just started to deal with such expressions in this lockdown period. So there may be something which hasn't striked me yet.. Please help! And yeah, the answer is $e$.

Comment: Yes something similar. Only difference is in the lower bounds of $n$ but interesting and a little bit confusing for me since $n=1$ gives the answer 1 and $n=0$ gives the answer $e$. I will try to solve the mystery!! Thanks.

Comment: That is just a minor detail, just subtract/add the term with $n=0$ accordingly, the method for the main series is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your sum equals
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k!}}} }  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n \cdot \frac{1}{{n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(n - 1)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n!}}}  = e.
$$

Comment: Ahh for some seconds. Nice and clear though.

Comment: Thank you so much... This proves, how dumb I am! Thanks...

Comment: One more query, will you please elaborate the second line? I mean how did $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac 1{k! }=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n! }$$ come?

Comment: At first glance it seemed obvious to me but now I'm struggling with it.

Comment: If you write the first sum out like $$
\left( {\frac{1}{{1!}} + \frac{1}{{2!}} + \frac{1}{{3!}} + \frac{1}{{4!}} +  \cdots } \right) + \left( {\frac{1}{{2!}} + \frac{1}{{3!}} + \frac{1}{{4!}} +  \cdots } \right) + \left( {\frac{1}{{3!}} + \frac{1}{{4!}} +  \cdots } \right) + \left( {\frac{1}{{4!}} +  \cdots } \right)+\cdots,
$$ you can see that $\frac{1}{n!}$ appears exactly $n$ times.

Comment: Yes indeed! Thank you so much sir...

Answer (score 2):

Change order of summation
$$
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^\infty_{m>n}\frac{1}{m!}=\sum^\infty_{m=1}\sum^{m-1}_{n=0}\frac{1}{m!}=\sum^\infty_{m=1}\frac{m}{m!}=\sum^\infty_{m=0}\frac{1}{m!}=e$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious time.. And this definitely proves, how dumb I am! Thanks...

Comment: ... just less experienced, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ n $ be a positivie integer, note that : $\mathrm{e}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k!}}=\frac{\mathrm{e}}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n}\mathrm{e}^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\cdot $

Since : \begin{aligned}\sum_{n=0}^{p}{\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n}\mathrm{e}^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}}-\int_{0}^{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\mathrm{e}^{-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\int_{0}^{1}{\sum_{n=p+1}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\mathrm{e}^{-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x}\underset{p\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\end{aligned}

We get that : \begin{aligned}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n}\mathrm{e}^{-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\lim_{p\to +\infty}{\sum_{n=0}^{p}{\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n}\mathrm{e}^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}}}=\int_{0}^{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\mathrm{e}^{-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x}=1\end{aligned}

Thus : \begin{aligned}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left(\mathrm{e}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k!}}\right)}=\mathrm{e}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n}\mathrm{e}^{-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\mathrm{e}\end{aligned}

Comment: The first line, is it a formula? Actually I am not familiar with this.

Comment: The first formula comes directly from Taylor's theorem, with the integral form of the remainder. But it can easily be proven using some Integration by Parts.

Comment: Okay I'll search for it. Thank you.